# Jquery Datepicker does not pop up in dialog box from jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, dialog, datepicker

In my jqGrid, I load and open a jQuery dialog box when a user clicks on a button in the pager as follows:

```
 var t1DocumentGridDialog = $('#t1_document_grid_dialog');
    grid.jqGrid({......
}).navGrid('#truck_grid_pager', {
        edit: false,
        add: false,
        del: false,
        search: false,
        refresh: true
    }).navButtonAdd('#truck_grid_pager', {
        caption: "T1 Documents",
        buttonicon: "ui-icon-document",
        id: "t1-documents",
        title: "Request T1 Documents",
        onClickButton: function () {
            t1DocumentGridDialog.load('${pageContext.request.contextPath}/t1DocumentsVisibility?truckId=' + selectedTruckId);
            t1DocumentGridDialog.dialog({title: "Truck Management - T1 request for truck " + selectedTruckId});
            t1DocumentGridDialog.dialog('open');
        }
    })
```

This works fine.

See below the jsp file of the page I load in the dialog box:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/jquery-ui.min.css"/>
    <style type="text/css">
        /* reduce size of datepicker */
        .ui-datepicker {font-size: 12px;}

        /* reduce autocomplete size */
        .ui-autocomplete {
            max-height: 100px;
            overflow-y: auto;
            /* prevent horizontal scrollbar */
            overflow-x: hidden;
            /* add padding to account for vertical scrollbar */
            padding-right: 20px;
        }

        /* reduce font size of autocomplete */
        .ui-autocomplete.ui-widget {
          font-size: 12px;
        }
    </style>
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var allDepotCodes = [${depotCodes}];
    var allMRNLevels = [${mrnLevels}];
    var allCountryNames = [${countryNames}];
    var carrierText;

    var requestCarrierText = function(){
        var depot = $("#depotCode").val();
        if(jQuery.inArray(depot, allDepotCodes) > -1) {
            clearElement("#overrideCarrier");
            disableElement("#overrideCarrier");
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/requestT1DocumentsAction',
                data: {
                    depotName: depot
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    enableAutoComplete("#overrideCarrier", data, true);
                    enableElement("#overrideCarrier");
                }
            });
        }
    }

    var clearElement = function(elementId){
        $(elementId).val("");
    };

    var enableElement = function(elementId){
        $(elementId).attr("disabled", false);
    };

    var disableElement = function(elementId){
        $(elementId).attr("disabled", true);
    };

    var enableAutoComplete = function(elem, autoCompleteValues, isAString) {
        if(autoCompleteValues != undefined && autoCompleteValues.length > 0) {
            var values;
            if(isAString) {
                values = autoCompleteValues.split(",");
            } else {
                values = autoCompleteValues;
            }
            $(elem).autocomplete({
                source: values,
                delay: 0,
                minLength: 2
            });
        }
    };

    var populateDropDownList = function(elementId, dropDownValues) {
        var element = document.getElementById(elementId);
        for(var i = 0; i < dropDownValues.length; i++) {
            var opt = document.createElement('option');
            opt.innerHTML = dropDownValues[i];
            opt.value = dropDownValues[i];
            element.appendChild(opt);
        }
    };

    var initializeDatePicker = function(elementId) {
        $(elementId).datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
            showOn: 'button',
            changeYear: true,
            changeMonth: true,
            buttonImageOnly: true,
            buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif",
            buttonText: "Select date",
            onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
                alert(dateText);
            }
        });
    };

    var requestT1Document = function(){
    };

    $(document).ready(function(){
        enableAutoComplete("#licencePlateCountry", allCountryNames, false);
        initializeDatePicker("#trailerPickupDate");
        //$("#ui-datepicker-div").css("z-index", "1003" );
        jQuery('.ui-datepicker-trigger').click(function() {
            jQuery('#ui-datepicker-div').css('z-index', 1003);
        });
        populateDropDownList('depotCode', allDepotCodes);
        populateDropDownList('mrnLevel', allMRNLevels);
    });

</script>
<table style='font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;font-family:Lucida Grande, Lucida Sans, Arial, sans-serif'>
    <tr> <td>Trailer pickup date</td>
        <td ><input type="text" id="trailerPickupDate" style="width:180px"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr> <td>Pickup ID</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="pickupId" style="width:180px"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr> <td>Depot code</td>
        <td><select id="depotCode" onchange="requestCarrierText()" style="width:183px"></select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr> <td>Override Carrier - Service</td>
        <td ><input type="text" id="overrideCarrier" style="width:180px" disabled></td>
    </tr>
    <tr> <td>MRN level</td>
        <td><select id="mrnLevel" style="width:183px"></select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr> <td>Truck license plate</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="trkLicensePlate" style="width:180px"> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr> <td>License plate country</td>
        <td ><input type="text" id="licencePlateCountry" style="width:180px"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr> <td colspan='2'><br><input type="button" value="Confirm" onclick="requestT1Document()"
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr> <td colspan='2'><br>
        <div align="left" id="t1InfoMessage"
             style="width:auto; height:auto;
                    font-family: Lucida Grande, Lucida Sans, Arial, sans-serif;
                    font-size: 11; color: green"> Info Message will be displayed here!
        </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

When I click on the calendar image (for 'Trailer pickup date' element), the datepicker does not load. However if I load the jsp file in a simple webpage without jqgrid, the datepicker pops up if I click on the calendar image

Comment: Please try to create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: @Thorsten: I made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/njiterry/vwb1c0mk/22/). If you click on the 'Docs' button, the dialog is loaded and you can access the datepicker. Everything works here because I do everything in one javascipt file and 1 webpage. In my project, when the button is clicked, a new jsp file(with t's own jaavascript) is loaded. Maybe the solution is to use one jsp file and 1 javascript file.